# How Can I apply "Right-To-Left Text Direction" in Word2016 by default?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, right-to-left

I have two problem with Right-To-Left Text Direction in Word2016:

**First:** every time I open Word2016 the Left-To-Right Text Direction is on and It is very annoying for me because I usually write Persian language.

**Second:** Ok after I set it "Left-To-Right" and I write in word and it works well at start. But it happens a lot during typing, When I press some Buttons in order to type in Persian language or I am changing language It change to "Right-To-Left" again and I should change it again and. this happens a lot of times.    I don't know when it exactly happens But I checked When I use Ctrl+Shift Buttons it change.(Maybe It happens other times too,I am not sure)

I use Windows 8.1

**Edit:** for the second problem I switched "keyboard Layout" in control panel to "Not Assigned" But still have the same problem in word when I press "Ctrl+Shift"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no way to do that. But you can press less buttons to change text direction by placing them at the quick access bar. Expand the arrow button in quick access bar, click More Commands, Then, you have to choose commands to add to the toolbar. If you can’t see the “left-to-right” command, select All Commands from the first menu. Scroll down and add left to right and right to left buttons. Then you'll find them at the quick access bar like an arrow after paragraph mark.

But still there is a workaround. Open an empty word document, type some words in LTR mode, then save the document, then delete those words and save again. Then word will automatically input all words in LTR.

Answer (score 1):

The First Question

I suggest you right click the document > Paragraph > Direction: Right-to-Left > Set As Default > All documents based on the Normal.dotm template > OK.

[image]

The Second Question

I can reproduce your issue, pressing Ctrl + Shift will change the alignment and direction even I set them as hotkey to switch Persian language.

I have no Windows 8.1, pressing Win + Space works correctly in my Windows 10.